# Given $a$ and $c$ positive numbers, is there a function $h$ such that $h(-ax)= -ch(x)$ for all $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Given $a>1$ and $c$ a positive number, is there a (no trivial) function $h$ such that $$h(-ax)= -ch(x)$$ for all $x$?.

I know that $h(x)=c^{\log_a|x|}$  satisfies $h(ax)=ch(x)$, however I am not sure how to deal with the $-a$ , $-c$ version.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If $a=1$, $c=2$, you'd need to have $h(x)=4h(x)$... Did you mean to specify $a>1$?

Comment: oh yes right $a>1$

Comment: Your title needs fixing. In the title, you require that $h$ is positive.

Comment: Yes so sorry, I just realized

Comment: Just a function, not necessarily continuous, right?

Comment: right, no need to be continuous

Comment: Define $h(x)$ for $x>0$ exactly the way you did, and for $x<0$ using the equation in the title.

Answer (score 3):

For such $h$, we have 
$$ h(a^2x)=c^2h(x).$$
In particular, $h(0)=-ch(0)$, so $h(0)=0$ or $c=-1$.
Let $g\colon[0,1)\to \Bbb R$ be arbitrary  and define $h$ as follows:

- if $x>0$, let $h(x)=(c^2)^{\lfloor \log_{a^2} x\rfloor }\cdot g(\log_{a^2} x \bmod 1)$
- if $x<0$, let $h(x)=-ch(-ax)$
- let $h(0)=0$ (or, if $c=-1$, take an arbitrary value)

These choices are both possible for arbitrary $g$, and on the other hand necessary by the conditions on $h$.

What if we want $h$ to be continuous?
Then to begin with, $g$ must be continuous and  $\lim_{g\to 1} g(x)=c^2g(0)$.
Then

- If $|c|>1$, this makes $\lim_{x\to 0} h(x)=0$, so  $h$ is continuous.
- If $c=-1$, the only globally continuous solutions have $g$ constant and so $h$ constant as well.
- If $c=+1$ or $|c|<1$, the only continuous solution is the zero function.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such functions exist.

Presumably by non-trivial, you mean not the zero function.

It's clear that we must have $h(0)=0$, so we start with that declaration.

Next, define an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}{\setminus}\{0\}$ by $x\equiv y$ if $x=(-a)^ky$, for some integer $k$.

For each equivalence class, choose one representative $r$ and define $h(r)=1$.

That declaration uniquely determines $h(x)$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}{\setminus}\{0\}$ with $x\equiv r$.

Thus, $h$ is defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.